# Tone.js test with JEST error: "ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined"

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, tone.js

I'm creating an app in **Typescript** with [**Tone.js**](https://tonejs.github.io/), and I'm using [**Jest**](https://jestjs.io/) to test it.

I have a `Musician` class:

```js
import * as Tone from 'tone';

export class Musician {
    instrument: Tone.Synth;

    constructor() {
        this.instrument = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
    }
}
```

And this is where I test it:

```js
import { Musician } from '../src/musician';

test("Musician has an instrument", () => {
    const musician = new Musician();

    expect(musician.instrument).toBeDefined();
});
```

When I run this test I get this: [image: terminal output].

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

And this is my `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Jest runs as a node.js script and AudioBuffer and Web Audio in general are not available in a node.js environment.

You basically have to mock the whole Web Audio API to test your audio things. But I would have a look at the tone.js library itself on how they test it.

https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/blob/dev/test/helper/SourceTests.ts

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should import only required tools

```js
// business.layer.js
import { Synth, PolySynth } from 'tone'

...

const synth = new PolySynth(Synth).toDestination()
```

Secondly, you should mock the used operation in your test file

```js
// *.test.js
jest.mock('tone', () => {
  return {
    PolySynth: jest.fn(),
    Synth: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return { toDestination: jest.fn() }
    })
  }
})
```